# I can't reach the Label on the Panel

Tags: c#, winforms, label, panel

```
public void blockControl()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (game.wordCount < i + 1)
        {
            Label lbl = (Label)game.Controls["wordLabel" + (i + 1).ToString()];
            lbl.Visible = false;
            Panel a1 =  (Panel)game.Controls["wordLabel" + (i + 1).ToString()];
            a1.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I access the labels in the user control.

But if i put labels on the panel
lbl=0  is happening

What should i do to reach?

I solved this way

```
public void blockControl()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (form1.harfSayisi < i + 1)
        {
            Panel abc = (Panel)form1.Controls["panel" + (i + 1).ToString()];
            Label lbl = (Label)abc.Controls["lblHarf" + (i + 1).ToString()];
            lbl.Visible = false;
            abc.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try looping the `Controls` collection of the **panel**?

Comment: `myPanel.Controls["wordLabel" + (i + 1).ToString()];` (put the right panel name instead of mine `myPanel`)? Since the label is on panel, not on the `form1`

Comment: Don't post *Thanks* and solutions in the question. If you have solved the problem, then post an answer that shows the code you came up with and explains why that code solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can search RECURSIVELY using `Controls.Find()`.  This way you don't need to get a reference to the Panel first.  The search will find the control no matter how deeply nested it is inside other containers.

Shortened code could then be:

```
Label lbl = form1.Controls.Find("lblHarf" + (i + 1).ToString(), true).FirstOrDefault() as Label;
if (lbl != null)
{
    // ... do something with "lbl" ...
}
```